# A norm inequality in an euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that in an euclidean space $V$, for every $x$ and $y$ in $V$ and for any real number $a$, the following holds:

$$(x|y) = 0 \implies \|x\| \leq \|x + ay\|$$

How can I proceed?

Comment: Square both sides and calculate directly $\lVert x+ay\rVert^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\|x + ay\|^2=(x + ay|x + ay)=\|x\|^2+(x | ay)+(ay |x )+|a|^2\|y\|^2$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Actually I managed to get to that part, but I cant go more than that really. Been stuck here for some time trying to figure what to do.

Comment: Evaluate $(x | ay)$, $(ay |x )$ and note that $|a|^2\|y\|^2\geq 0$

Comment: Ok I get it... the thing was (x|y) and (y|x) are the same lol didnt notice that.